# RE: Is it possible to import a script from an URL using node.js?

Tags: node.js

Since this question already exists, but I don't know if that the right choice to do after es2015 update to javascript, could someone recomment some easy way to do that in node LTS?

Comment: You can download it with your favorite http library (such as `got()` or `axios()` or `node-fetch()`) and once you have it downloaded locally into memory, you can use `eval()` to run it.  If it's actually a module, then you can save it to disk and load it with `require()`.  The latest `import` syntax will support URLs, but I don't think node.js yet allows it to be anything other than a file URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can download it with your favorite http library (such as `got()` or `axios()` or `node-fetch()`) and once you have it downloaded locally into memory, you can use `eval()` to run it. If it's actually a module, then you can save it to disk and load it with `require()`. The latest import syntax will support URLs, but I don't think node.js yet allows it to be anything other than a file URL.

Here's an example, using the `got()` library to download the script and save it to a file:

```
const {promisify} = require('util');
const pipeline = promisify(require('stream').pipeline);
const fs = require('fs');
const got = require('got');

pipeline(
  got.stream('http://yourURLhere'),
  fs.createWriteStream('yourfile.js')
).then(result => {
    // load the script
    require(`./yourfile.js`)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Note, it can be done in a few less steps with `.pipe()` (as commonly illustrated), but `.pipe()` does not forward errors from the readstream whereas `pipeline()` does.